# wx.xml.XmlResource.Get().LoadPanel: doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

Loading XRC wx.Panel on existing instance does not work.
There is no error reported, although on any attempt to display it's empty.

**Erroneous method:**

```
import wx
import wx.xrc

class SomePanelViewModel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        xmlResource = wx.xrc.XmlResource('SomePanelView.xrc')
        xmlResource.LoadPanel(panel=self, parent=parent, name='SomePanelView')
```

The XRC file is valid, because other method of `LoadPanel` works without a problem.
So the panel is populated and visible.

**Working method:**

```
xmlResource = wx.xrc.XmlResource('SomePanelView.xrc')
panel = xmlResource.LoadPanel(parent=parent, name='SomePanelView')
```

It is also worth to mention that both methods work for wx.Dialog without an issue.

I have also tried to run methods like 'Show' on broken panel.
Unfortunately without any effect.

I'm startled and confused.
Has anybody dealt with it before?
Any suggestions? Solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I'm answering my own question. xD

The problem looks like a library bug.

**Therefore I decided to make a workaround:**

```
class XrcPanelView(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        xrcFilePath = 'path/to/your.xrc'
        xmlResource = wx.xrc.XmlResource(xrcFilePath)
        self._xrcPanel = xmlResource.LoadPanel(parent=self, name='ViewName')

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self._xrcPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 0)
```

That way you inherit a panel and apply you XRC panel on it.
It's not a perfect solution.
Although it achieves my goal.
I needed to encapsulate some extra initialization steps within one view class.

Hope somebody would enjoy. ;)